# javascript / DOM - how to access the property of an object

Tags: javascript, dom, object, properties

seems like an easy question but I can't get this. I have a property I'm trying to access using console.log in javascript. If I do console.log(intersects) - I get the object, with a list of all of its properties. One of them is object, and it has a child property of name "s2" - that's the property I want to be able to access in my log statement. But if I try:

`console.log(intersects.object.name)` - I get undefined. I've attached a screenshot from the inspector in Chrome. Any idea how to access this?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `intersects` is actually an array of objects; try `intersects[0].object.name`.

(You can tell by the square brackets around the parent Object in the inspector.)